# Auto-resizing window

Tags: objective-c, macos, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, macos-sierra

I'd like to embed a Tabbar or a TabViewController using a container into a ViewController of a Window for a macOS App. The two ViewControllers of the Tabbar / TabVC should have different heights, a tall one and a small/flat one.

The point is, that I'd like to automatically resize the whole window height when the Tabbar / TabVC changes its ViewController. This way the window is always as small as possible and doesn't show any unused and empty space.

This is my current storyboard, which (of course) doesn't resize the windows:

[image: Storyboard]

Does anybody have a hint, how to automatically resize the window according to the size of the selected ViewController in the Tabbar or TabVC?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `preferredContentSize` in `viewWillAppear` like:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear
{
    [super viewWillAppear];
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.fittingSize.width, 194);
}
```

You can also use `self.preferredContentSize = self.view.fittingSize;` if that works for you.
But I'm not sure if this will animate the change for you.